# Non-user-friendly message when trying to edit post with pending suggested editions

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, design, alerts

I just tried to edit a post in stackoverflow and got the following message:

> [image: There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.]

It reads:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.

First of all, I understand the message. However, I don't think the way it is displayed is the most appropriate one. Actually, once I clicked on the "edit" link I got a webpage which ONLY content was the one I mentioned before. I mean, that was the source code of the page... there are not even HTML tags there!

There are many ways to provide this information without making the user hit the back button of the browser. I think some options that wouldn't require to reinvent the wheel are:

- Showing a message similar like the one when you click on "flag"
- Showing a message in a similar way like the one you get when clicking on "link"

To make it a bit clearer, this are the steps I followed and the result I got:

1. Opened a question
2. Clicked on edit

   Expected result: Being able to edit the post OR having a friendly message explaining why I can not edit the post

   Real result: I got redirected to the URL "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/[post_id]/edit" which only contained the text mentioned before. To put it in PHP terms, the webpage displayed the result of an `echo` of the message, just that. So, after seeing an almost-white page, the user has to click on the back button of the browser to go back to the question.

Comment: This also applies to locked posts. They only contain text

Comment: @Evgenko423 such major overhaul of an old post is not how it is supposed to be. If things have changed in the meanwhile start a new post, and link to this post.

Comment: @Luuklag What major overhaul? I just added duplicate links and said why it makes more sense now. The rest was just a cleanup of original post. About new post: according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/578924) we **shouldn't re-post things that haven't been declined**, so I'm bumping it here. Sorry for the rant, but I don't see my effort being respected: I wrote it yesterday as a comment to the answer, but people don't seem to read, they just upvote the answer which describes behavior that they've never seen and no longer true...

Comment: @Luuklag I also followed [these suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398/578924).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when someone else already suggested an edit you won't have "edit" link at all.

So, sounds like one of these two cases:

1. Rare case where you and other person (with less than 2K rep) click the edit in the exact same time, less than millisecond difference.
2. Someone suggested an edit while you were viewing the page and before you clicked the *edit* button - if you would have reloaded, no edit link would appear.

If you can elaborate on your suggestions it might be good idea though. :)

Comment: Sure. It is not actually about when this happens but rather to display it in a better way. I'm adding some steps to the question

Comment: Since the Edit link doesn't get hidden or inactive anymore (e.g. "The edit queue is full" message is shown as a popup only after you click on it), could this request be implemented, please?

Comment: @EvgenKo423 the pop up is kind of what this request is about, if you have a different idea please post it as answer, or even start a new request.

Comment: @Shadow I understand that, but this message is still being showed on a separate empty page.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 no, and if so it's a bug so please report.

Comment: @Shadow I've seen this happening in the past 4 months. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/578924) we shouldn't re-post things that haven't been declined, so I'm bumping it here.