# Display more user-friendly message about a question/answer that has a pending suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I know this is a little thing, but would it be possible to change the message that appears when a user tries to edit a question/answer that has a pending suggested edit? At the moment you see the following text on a plain white background:

> "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes."

I think the above in a popup message (or redirection back to the question with the popup message) would be better suited over the current text on a simple white page.

This was mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121279/non-user-friendly-message-when-trying-to-edit-post-with-pending-suggested-editio) two years ago, but nothing came of it.

Comment: You should get involved with the dupe you linked to. Making a new question doesn't really help get any movement on a topic, in fact it can hinder it because the votes/activity from your question here could have been on the other one :) Start a bounty, upvote it, comment, or add an answer if you feel you have some additional arguments in favour :)